# Error during Xcode installation

Tags: ios, xcode, installation

The following error occurred during my Xcode installation on my Mac.

```
05/04/12 11:10:15.852 AM com.apple.SecurityServer: Failed to authorize right 'system.install.app-store-software' by client '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/installd' [391] for authorization created by '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app' [376]
```

My Mac OS X version is: 10.5.7 Leopard and My Xcode version is: 4.3.2

Please give me a solution, Thanks in advance

-Vineeth N K

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error most likely because you are trying to install a release of Xcode that is made to run on OS X Lion 10.7 and up on a 10.5.7 system.